# How to split array into all possible combinations

Tags: php

How can I loop through an array, split it into two arrays and run a function for each possible combination? Order does not matter.

```
// Original array
$array = array('a','b','c','d','e');

// Result 1
array('a');
array('b','c','d','e');

// Result 2
array('a', 'b');
array('c','d','e');

// Result 3
array('a', 'c');
array('b','d','e');
```

And so on...

Comment: That's easy, do you want just the output or the arrays

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix See my comment on your answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's to much math for me.... lol

Comment: Do you consider `[a,c],[b,d,e]` to be the same as `[c,a],[e,b,d]`?

Comment: Do you consider `[a,b],[c,d,e]` and `[c,d,e],[a,b]` to be the same?

Comment: @Nick and ultimater yes, I consider it the same. As I said in the question, order does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take at this:

```
<?php
$ar = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

function permuteThrough($ar, $callback, $allowMirroredResults = true, $mode = 'entry', $desiredLeftCount = null, $left = [], $right = [])
{
    switch($mode)
    {
        case 'entry':
            // Logic:
            // Determine how many elements we're gonna put into left array
            $len = $allowMirroredResults ? count($ar) : floor(count($ar)/2);

            for($i=0; $i <= $len; $i++)
            {
                    call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $ar, $callback, $allowMirroredResults, 'permute',$i);
            }
            break;
        case 'permute':
            // We have nothing left to sort, let's tell our callback
            if( count($ar) === 0 )
            {
                $callback($left,$right);
                break;
            }

            if( count($left) < $desiredLeftCount )
            {
                // Note: PHP assigns arrays as clones (unlike objects)
                $ar1 = $ar;
                $left1 = $left;
                $left1[] = current(array_splice($ar1,0,1));
                call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $ar1, $callback, $allowMirroredResults, 'permute', $desiredLeftCount, $left1, $right);
            }

            // This check is needed so we don't generate permutations which don't fulfill the desired left count
            $originalLength = count($ar) + count($left)+count($right);
            if( count($right) < $originalLength - $desiredLeftCount )
            {
                $ar2 = $ar;
                $right1 = $right;
                $right1[] = current(array_splice($ar2,0,1));
                call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $ar2, $callback, $allowMirroredResults, 'permute', $desiredLeftCount, $left, $right1);
            }
            break;
    }
}

function printArrays($a,$b)
{
    echo '['.implode(',',$a).'],['.implode(',',$b)."]\n";
}

permuteThrough($ar, 'printArrays', true); // allows mirrored results
/*
[],[a,b,c,d,e]
[a],[b,c,d,e]
[b],[a,c,d,e]
[c],[a,b,d,e]
[d],[a,b,c,e]
[e],[a,b,c,d]
[a,b],[c,d,e]
[a,c],[b,d,e]
[a,d],[b,c,e]
[a,e],[b,c,d]
[b,c],[a,d,e]
[b,d],[a,c,e]
[b,e],[a,c,d]
[c,d],[a,b,e]
[c,e],[a,b,d]
[d,e],[a,b,c]
[a,b,c],[d,e]
[a,b,d],[c,e]
[a,b,e],[c,d]
[a,c,d],[b,e]
[a,c,e],[b,d]
[a,d,e],[b,c]
[b,c,d],[a,e]
[b,c,e],[a,d]
[b,d,e],[a,c]
[c,d,e],[a,b]
[a,b,c,d],[e]
[a,b,c,e],[d]
[a,b,d,e],[c]
[a,c,d,e],[b]
[b,c,d,e],[a]
[a,b,c,d,e],[]

*/
echo "==============\n"; // output separator
permuteThrough($ar, 'printArrays', false); // doesn't allow mirrored results
/*
[],[a,b,c,d,e]
[a],[b,c,d,e]
[b],[a,c,d,e]
[c],[a,b,d,e]
[d],[a,b,c,e]
[e],[a,b,c,d]
[a,b],[c,d,e]
[a,c],[b,d,e]
[a,d],[b,c,e]
[a,e],[b,c,d]
[b,c],[a,d,e]
[b,d],[a,c,e]
[b,e],[a,c,d]
[c,d],[a,b,e]
[c,e],[a,b,d]
[d,e],[a,b,c]
*/
```

My `permuteThrough` function takes three arguments.
The array, the callback, and an optional boolean indicating whether or not you want to allow mirrored results.
The logic is pretty straight forward:
First decide how many elements we want to put into our left array.
Then Recursively call the function like so:
Our working array with the remaining elements to sort.
Shift an element off and put it into the left array. The result gets sent to another layer of recursion.
Shift an element off and put it into the right array. The result gets sent to another layer of recursion.
If there's no elements left to shift off, call our callback with the resulting left and right arrays.
Finally, make sure we're not going over the desired left array element size determined by the for loop at the beginning and make sure the right size doesn't become so big that it makes the desired left size impossible to satisfy.  Normally this would be done by two separate functions.  One to decide how many elements should go into the left array.  And one to be used for recursion.  But instead I tossed in another argument to the recursion function to eliminate the need for a separate function so it can all be handled by the same recursive function.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks @Ultimater. +1 for the option to exclude mirrored.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I can do:

```
class Combos
{

    /**
     * getPossible then getDivide
     * 
     * @param array $input
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPossibleAndDivided( array $input )
    {
        return $this->getMultiShiftAndDivided( $this->getPossible( $input ) );
    }

    /**
     * return all possible combinations of input
     * 
     * @param array $input
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPossible( array $inputs )
    {
        $result = [];

        if ( count( $inputs ) <= 1 ) {
            $result = $inputs;
        } else {
            $result = array();
            foreach($inputs as $input){

                //make it an array
                $first = [ $input ];  

                //get all inputs not in first
                $remaining = array_diff( $inputs, $first );

                //send the remaining stuff but to ourself
                $combos = $this->getPossible( $remaining );//recursive

                //iterate over the above results (from ourself)
                foreach( $combos as $combo ) {
                    $last = $combo;
                    //convert to array if it's not
                    if( !is_array( $last ) ) $last = [ $last ];
                    //merge them
                    $result[] = array_merge( $first, $last );
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * shift and divide a multi level array
     *
     * @param array $array
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMultiShiftAndDivided( array $mArray )
    {
        $divided = [];
        foreach ( $mArray as $array ) {
            $divided = array_merge($divided, $this->getShiftAndDivided( $array ));
        }
        return $divided;
    }

    /**
     * shift and divide a single level array
     * 
     * @param array $array
     * @return array
     */
    public function getShiftAndDivided( array $array )
    {        
        $divided = [];
        $array1 = [];
        while( count( $array ) ){
            $array1[] = array_shift( $array );
            $divided[] = [ $array, $array1 ];
        }

        return $divided;
    }
}
```

**How it works**

Top level, I don't want to get into all the details. This is basically a 2 step process or at least it was easier to figure it out that way.  I built it in a class to keep everything neat. It also allows better unit testing and re-usability.

This requires 2 operations, or at least it was easier for me to do it in 2 instead of as 1.  They are combined in this method

```
public function getPossibleAndDivided( array $input )
{
   return $this->getMultiShiftAndDivided( $this->getPossible( $input ) );
}
```

This is the main reason I made it a class, to keep everything packaged nicely together.  I would call this a wrapper method.

**Step One**

*$Combos->getPossible(array $input)*

1. **if** only one item remains, return `$inputs`.

   - this is all the combinations it can ever have (its just a single element after all).
2. **else** It iterates thought `$inputs` with foreach as `$input`

   1. Wraps `$input` as an array named `$first`

      - this is a single element from `$inputs`
   2. Gets the remaining elements in `$inputs` in a non-destructive way as `$remaining`

      - using array_diff we need both elements as arrays (see aabove)
   3. recursive call to `$this->getPossible($remaining)` (see #1) and returns as `$combos`
   4. Iterates over `$combos` foreach as `$combo`

      1. `$combo` is assigned to `$last` and turned into an array, if its not

         - sometimes combo is an array with several elements
         - sometimes is a single element. It depends on the recursive call
      2. We add to our result set the merger of `$first` and `$last`

         - we need both as arrays so we can merge, without causing nesting
3. **End** Anything in `$result` is returned.

This basically rotates though all the combinations of the array and returns them in an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
            [4] => e
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => e
            [4] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => d
            [3] => c
            [4] => e
        )
 ...
    [117] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => d
            [2] => b
            [3] => c
            [4] => a
        )

    [118] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => d
            [2] => c
            [3] => a
            [4] => b
        )

    [119] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => d
            [2] => c
            [3] => b
            [4] => a
        )

)
```

Yes it returns `119` results, no I will not include them all.

**Step Two**

Don't forget the above output is a multi-dimensional array (this is important below).

*$Combos->getMultiShiftAndDivided(array $mArray)*

This method is intended to be used with multi-dimensional arrays (hence its name). We get this from "Step 1". Its basically a wrapper for *$Combos->getShiftAndDivided($array)*

1. Iterates over `$mArray` foreach as `$array`
2. It calls `$this->getShiftAndDivided($array)` returns and merges with `$divided`.

   - there was no need to store the results, so I didn't waste a variable on it.

Output example:

```
$input = array(array('a','b','c','d','e'));
print_r($combos->getMultiShiftAndDivided($input));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b
                    [1] => c
                    [2] => d
                    [3] => e
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                )

        )
    ....
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                    [3] => d
                    [4] => e
                )

        )

)
```

*$Combos->getShiftAndDivided(array $array)*

This method is intended to be used single level arrays.

1. Loops as long as the count of `$array` is more then 0, while loop
2. `$array1` gets the first element from `$array` added and that element is removed from `$array` (destructively)
3. we store both `$array` and `$array1` in our results `$divided`

   - this records there current "state" at that moment
4. when there are no more items in `$array` we return our results

Output example:

```
$input = array('a','b','c','d','e');
print_r($combos->getShiftAndDivided($input));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b
                    [1] => c
                    [2] => d
                    [3] => e
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                )

        )
....
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
                [2] => c
                [3] => d
                [4] => e
            )

    )

)
```

Basically this shifts the elements of a single array to two result arrays and records their state on each shift.  I made it 2 functions so that it could be tested easier and be re-used easier.

Another issue is its kind of hard to check for multi-dimensional arrays. I know how to do it, but I didn't feel like it because it's kind of ugly and there is a better way. I say that because its possible to use a one level array in what is `getMultiShiftAndDivided` and it wouldn't give you what you would expect.  Probably you would get an error like this:

```
//I say probably, but I actually test it ... lol
Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array
```

Which could be confusing, one could think the code is buggered.  So by having the second method call with a type set into it `getShiftAndDivided( array $array )`.  When the wrapping method tries to call this with a string its going to blow up, but in a better way:

```
Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Combos::getShiftAndDivided() must be of the type array, string given
```

Hopefully that makes sense, it's something I always try to do in cases like this.  It just makes life easier in the long run. Both function return the data in the same format, which is convenient (your welcome).

**Summary**

So the sum of what this does, is find all the combinations of our input, then it takes those and breaks each one into shifted and divided up array.  There for it stands to reason that we will have all the possible combinations divided up into 2 arrays anyway possible.  Because that is pretty much exactly what I said.

Now I am not 100% it does that, you can check them if you want, it returns like 599 elements at the end.  So good luck on that, I would suggest testing just the results of *$combos->getPossible($input)*. If that has all the combinations like it should, then this will have all that it needs.  I am not sure if it returns duplicates, I don't think that was specified.  But I didn't really check it.

You can call the main method like this:

```
$input = array('a','b','c','d','e');  
print_r((new Combos)->getPossibleAndDivided($input));
```

[Test It!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd8b0cb30e9a57cc0360233f80150f6161af5bb9)

*P.S. I spell breaks as brakes, but I can write code this, go figure...*

Comment: Upvote for the detailed answer. It returns that many because it cares about sort order. I don't care about sort order. So now I just need to filter out the dupes.